# preg_match strong tag followed by description

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, preg-match

I've this in my html content, from which I want to extract some text:

```
<p>
    <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>
    <br />Text I want to extract including "<br>" <br /><br />
    <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>
    <br />Text I want to extract<br /><br />
    <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>
    <br />Text I want to extract ...
```

As you can see there is always a strong tag followed by some description.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this with preg_match or preg_match_all or is it better to use an domcrawler here?

Best,
Christian

Comment: Dom will be the best option.

Comment: Please, show the result you want. Do you want to extract the tag or not? Do you want to keep the linebreaks? Do you want to keep indentation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$str = '<p>
    <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>
    <br />Text I want to extract including <br> <br /><br />
    <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>
    <br />Text I want to extract<br /><br />
    <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>
    <br />Text I want to extract ...';
$tname = 'strong';
$pattern = "/<$tname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tname>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Did you try it? it doesn't extract `Text I want to extract including <br> ` as requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<p>    <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>
<br />Text I want to extract including "<br>" <br /><br /> 
 <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>    
<br />Text I want to extract<br /><br />    
<strong>Text I want to extract</strong>    
<br />Text I want to extract ...';

$pattern = "#</strong\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*?strong\b[^>]*>#s";
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I also want to extract the text between the strong tags.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the text between the strong end tags. For example "<br />Text I want to extract including "<br>" <br /><br /> " or "<br />Text I want to extract<br /><br /> ". Sorry for the misunderstood. I want to extract <strong>TEXT 1</strong>TEXT 2<br />

Comment: Looks good. I just need the text "<br />Text I want to extract ...'". Its the last line. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Thanks!. It it helps you please upvote/accept my answer @user7430054

Answer (score 0):

Try Dom to get the string inside strong tags same can be done for other tags:

```
<?php
$str='<p>
    <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>
    <br />Text I want to extract including "<br>" <br /><br />
    <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>
    <br />Text I want to extract<br /><br />
    <strong>Text I want to extract</strong>
    <br />Text I want to extract ...
    </p>
';

$dom=new DomDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($str);
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('strong');
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8424c167f80e9e0b179169f42e96827725e9350c)